# parcel watch not working:module not found

Tags: javascript, parceljs

My code successfully compiles when i run parcel with "parcel serve" or "parcel build"
but when i run with "parcel watch", i run into an error module not found

my package.json:

```
   {
      "name": "geolocation-places",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "get location of nearyby places",
      "source": "./frontend/public/js/controller/index.js",
     "scripts": {
      "watch:js": "parcel watch ./frontend/public/js/controller/index.js --dist-dir ./frontend/public ",
      "sass-dev": "sass --watch --update --style=expanded frontend/public/sass/home.scss:frontend/public/css/styles.css",
      "sass-prod": "sass --no-source-map --style=compressed 
        sass/main.scss:css/stylesCompiled.css"
 },


"author": "eloho",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
  "node": "14.15.3"
},



"dependencies": {
    "array-sort": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.23.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "esri-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.6",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.6.0",
    "parcel-transformer-ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10"
  }
}
```

Thanks...